# Executing Dynamically generated T-Sql Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is my `Sample` table

[image]

In the above table i will evaluating the fields coming in `No Column Name` like this:

```
--Evaluates Expression
declare @ExpressionString varchar(max)
set @ExpressionString = 'Select ' + @ExpressionString 
Exec (@ExpressionString )
```

Now the above was working fine until i was getting the output from a procedure, however i am unable to do this:

```
Select (Select  [No Column Name]) from Sample
```

I expected the result to be:

```
AI
```

Which i will get with this:

```
exec ('select Left(''AI 0400'',2)')
```

How can i achieve this?

With this:

```
Select (EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL Value) from Sample
```

From Sample i am getting error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to select dynamic column, which would be passed to you as parameter? If thats the case `exec` is the right answer, it is made for dynamic sql statements.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to evaluate all the expressions in the `Sample` table and return the results as a single result set.

One way to do that would be to traverse the entire table to build a dynamic query of this kind:

```
SELECT Left('AI 0400',2) UNION ALL SELECT Right('0000' + 'AI 0400',4) UNION ALL ...
```

and then execute the resulting script.

The problem of building a query of that kind essentially boils down to a problem of concatenating multiple rows into a single string value, which is an [often asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+concatenate+multiple+rows) on Stack Overflow. One of the most common solutions to that problem in SQL Server is using a `FOR XML` query, and here's how it could be applied to your situation:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql =
  STUFF(
    (
      SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT ' + Value + ' '
      FROM Sample
      FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
    1, 10, ''  -- these are set to remove the initial 'UNION ALL '
  )
;

PRINT(@sql);  -- view the (first 4K chars of the) script before running
--EXECUTE (@sql);  -- uncomment if your inspection didn't reveal anything wrong
```

Comment: Only consideration is to be careful with using FOR XML PATH and escape characters. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2013/06/13/24296.aspx

Answer (score 0):

here u go for the updated query, this is the best thing i can do due lack of information, i believe there are no something like Select [Select * from sample] From sample, the only thing that u can do it write your dynamic query correctly and execute it by using sp_executesql, off cause u do can pass your parameter to filter it as well, cheer brother

```
declare @ExpressionString nvarchar(max)
set @ExpressionString = 'Select [No Column Name] From Sample' 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @ExpressionString
```

2013-08-20 0930AM below is updated query , try it =)

```
Declare @t1 TABLE
(
NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('Left(''AI 0400'',2)')


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = 'Select ' + (SELECT NAME from @t1)


EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

2013-08-20 0950AM  here is another updated query for multiple column values

```
Declare @t1 TABLE
(
NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('Left(''AI 0400'',2)')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('Left(''AI 0400'',2)')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES ('Right(''0000'' + ''AI 0400'',4)')


DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @nTotalRec INT

SET @nTotalRec =(SELECT COUNT(NAME) FrOM @t1) +1

DECLARE @nCount INT
SET @nCount = 1
DECLARE @Condition NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Condition = ''
WHILE @nCount !=@nTotalRec
BEGIN

SET @Condition = @Condition + (
SELECT NAME FROM (
SELECT NAME,Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDeR BY NAME) FROM @t1) q 
WHERE Rn = @nCount) + ','
SET @nCount = @nCount +1
END

SET @Condition = LEFT(@Condition,LEN(@Condition)-1)

SET @query = 'Select ' + @Condition


EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: How to get the return value? Also i should be able to do this in the SQL Select statement

Comment: wait, i write the full statement for u

Comment: Question, how u get the no column name column? xD